# I am having issues using the if statement. I am not sure why

Tags: c++

I am having issues using the `if` statement. I am not sure why.

When the user enters an addition operation, the program works fine, but when the user enters a subtract, multiply, or divide operation, the program does not work as intended.

Written below is the assignment description:

> Write a program that takes an operation followed by two operands and
> outputs the result. For example:
>
> ```
> + 100 3.14
> * 4 5
> ```
>
> Read the operation into a string called `operation` and use an `if` statement to figure out which operation the user wants, for example, `if (operation=="+")`. Read the operands into variables of type `double`.
> Implement this for operations called `+`, `–`, `*`, `/`, `plus`, `minus`, `mul`, `and` `div` with their obvious meanings.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    cout<<"Enter an operation below following this template operation operand operand:\n\n";
    char user_operation;
    double user_operand_one, user_operand_two;
    cin>>user_operation;
    cin>>user_operand_one;
    cin>>user_operand_two;

    double plus_result, div_result, minus_result, mul_result;
    
    //formulas
    plus_result = user_operand_one + user_operand_two;
    minus_result = user_operand_one - user_operand_two;
    div_result = user_operand_one / user_operand_two;
    mul_result = user_operand_one * user_operand_two;

    if (user_operation == '+' || "plus") {
        cout<<'\n'<<plus_result;
    }

    else if (user_operation == '-' || "minus") {    
        cout<<'\n'<<minus_result;
    }

    else if (user_operation == '*' || "mul"){    
        cout<<'\n'<<mul_result;
    }

    else if (user_operation == '/' || "div"){    
        cout<<'\n'<<div_result;
    }
}
```

I am compiling with gcc version 12.2.0.

Comment: "plus" converted to bool is always true. So first if is always taken. It is unclear what you mean by it.

Comment: `a == b || c` - wrong, `a == b || a == c` - correct. But `char` can only hold a single character, and you're trying to compare it with a (multi-character) string.

Comment: Just dropping in to ensure the compile command being given starts with `g++` and not `gcc`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @Beginner Part of being a good programmer requires the skill to *follow directions*, which you are not doing.  The instructions explicitly told you to read in the `operation` as a **string**, not as a **single character**. It even gave you an example showing the `operation` being compared to a *string* value. A single `char` simply cannot handle values like `"plus"`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of things wrong here.

`user_operation` is of type `char`, this means a **single** character, not multiple characters, not zero characters. So `user_operation` can never equal `"plus"`. If you want to enter multiple characters you must change the type to `std::string`, i.e.

```
std::string user_operation;
```

If you want to compare something as equal to one thing or another then this is

```
if (user_operation == "+" || user_operation == "plus")
```

Your version

```
if (user_operation == "+" || "plus")
```

works in English, but it doesn't work in C++.

Comment: Always worth keeping in mind [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) as that's why the "English" version doesn't work.

Comment: @tadman I think there is more to it than operator precedence. Even if `||` had higher precedence than `==` it still doesn't work, you would also have to change `||` to some kind of set constructor, and `==` to mean is-a-member-of. Possible in some language, but not part of C++.

Comment: I mean that with the precedence the last part gets collapsed into one value, so it obviously can't compare against the two possible values, at least according to C++ rules as they exist today, as you point out.

Answer (score 2):

There are several problems here.

```
if (user_operation == '+' || "plus")
```

This is wrong and won't work. The logical `or` works on two Boolean operands. `user_operation == '+'` is one, but where is the other? The answer can be a bit counterintuitive: it is `true`, which is the result of conversion of a string literal to a `const char` pointer, and then to a `bool` value. You need to repeat the comparison:

```
if (user_operation == '+' || user_operation == "plus")
```

Which immediately reveals the second problem. Characters and strings are two different things. `user_operation` is a `char`, and so is `'+'`. `"plus"`, however, is a C-style *string literal*. You cannot directly compare it to a `char`, and if you could it won't have any sense, because a `char` holds a single character. I recommend working with `std::string` instead. You can compare an `std::string` to both `char` and C-style string literals.

Another, unrelated problem is that you are computing all results when you only need one. What happens if the user enters `+ 3 0`?

Comment: C is not really a strongly typed language...

Answer (score 0):

What is said about syntax problems is correct. But generally speaking, this is a problem of formal languages. So, when you parse some expression, consider reducing multiple variants of the same expression  to a single operation in the code. It means reducing complexity of your program itself without reducing the flexibility of your expression.

```cpp
...
int main()
....
    string user_operation;
....
    cin>>user_operation;
....
    //module 1, parse and simplify operations
    if (user_operation == "plus")       user_operation = "+";
    else if (user_operation == "minus") user_operation = "-";
    else if (user_operation == "mul")   user_operation = "*";
    else if (user_operation == "div")   user_operation = "/";
...
    //module 2: execute operations
    switch (user_operation[0])
    {
    case '+':  cout<< user_operand_one + user_operand_two<< endl; break;
    case '-':  cout<< user_operand_one - user_operand_two<< endl; break;
....
    default:
        cout<< "failed to compile expression "<< user_operation<< endl;
        return -1;
    }
....
```

There is one more problem. You do your all calculations in advance. For very simple, one time +-/* is not a problem. But it is a problem in real life, even for very simple expressions. When parsing some real expressions, these are not meant to be known in advance, but to be detected dynamically, then to be put in a calculation tree. When finished, iterating the tree and executing each node. So, you should approach in some way, without knowing the operator and result in advance. This means generating dynamically the code to be executed, then execute. In OOP style can be done like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct operer
{
    virtual double operator () (double, double) = 0;
};
struct: operer { double operator () (double a, double b) { return a + b; } } op_add;
struct: operer { double operator () (double a, double b) { return a - b; } } op_sub;
struct: operer { double operator () (double a, double b) { return a * b; } } op_mul;
struct: operer { double operator () (double a, double b) { return a / b; } } op_div;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Enter an operation below following this template operation operand operand:\n\n";
    string user_operation;
    double user_operand_one, user_operand_two;
    cin>>user_operation;
    cin>>user_operand_one;
    cin>>user_operand_two;

    //module 1: parse and simplify
    if (user_operation == "plus")       user_operation = "+";
    else if (user_operation == "minus") user_operation = "-";
    else if (user_operation == "mul")   user_operation = "*";
    else if (user_operation == "div")   user_operation = "/";

    //module 2: generating execution code
    operer* op;
    switch (user_operation[0])
    {
    case '+':  op = &op_add; break;
    case '-':  op = &op_sub; break;
    case '*':  op = &op_mul; break;
    case '/':  op = &op_div; break;
    default:
        cout<< "failed to compile expression "<< user_operation<< endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // module 3: executing the generated code
    cout<< op -> operator ()(user_operand_one, user_operand_two)<< endl;
    return 0;
}
```

There are also other ways of generating the execution code. For instance non OOP style, potentially slightly faster. Following can be done in VisualStudio, definitely can be done in all C++ compilers but maybe with different syntaxes:

```
double add(double a, double b) { return a + b; }
double sub(double a, double b) { return a - b; }

int main()
{
...
        //do all input and parsing here
... 

    //generate code
    double(*op) (double, double) = 0;
    switch (user_operation[0])
    {
    case '+':  op = &add; break;
    case '-':  op = &sub; break;
...
    //execute code
    cout << op(user_operand_one, user_operand_two) << endl;
```